# What's the policy on questions that already have an answer in another .SE?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

scifi.stackexchange has a peculiar scope. It tackles, as the name says, Science fiction and fantasy elements. However, these are usually distributed by Films, TV and Books.

For example, these two questions: [Why is Avada Kedavra Considered Unblockeable?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30805/why-is-avada-kedavra-considered-unblockable/30808#30808) and [Are Unforgiveable curses unblockeable in Harry Potter](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35130/are-unforgivable-curses-unblockable-in-harry-potter)

They are essentially dupes of one another, (if you exclude the fact that on scifi book canocity supercedes), however they are on different stack exchanges, and both fit their respective scopes.

How should these questions be handled?

Comment: Related: [Would questions tagged 'Science-Fiction' in Movies&TV fracture the network?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5107/21267)

Comment: I don't think they require any special handling, there doesn't seem to be a problem that needs to be solved.  If you think there is a problem, maybe add that to your question.

Comment: Related MSE discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates